# Getting a JSON error with fopen on php

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm trying to update a log.csv file everytime a user tries to log in. But it seems like the fopen is messing up with my json.parse, it's giving me an error of `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 47` but that error disappears whenever I remove the fopen lines.

The code is

```
<?php

$email = $_POST['email'];
$emailRet = new stdClass();
$data = array();
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    array_push($data, date("Y/m/d"), date("h:i:sa"), $email, 'false');
    $emailRet->error = 'false';
    $emailRet->message = 'email validated';
    $emailJson = json_encode($emailRet);
    echo $emailJson;
}else{
    array_push($data, date("Y/m/d"), date("h:i:sa"), $email, 'true');
    $emailRet->error = 'true';
    $emailRet->message = 'email is not valid';
    $emailJson = json_encode($emailRet);
    echo $emailJson;
}

$fp = fopen('../../log.csv', 'w');
foreach($data as $d){
    fputcsv($fp, $d);
}
fclose($fp);
```

This php file is used to respond to an ajax call btw.

Comment: Sounds like a warning / error might be getting output? What is being rendered to your browser?

Comment: Nothing, even the data that the ajax is supposed to receive doesn't fire. it seems like there's a problem with the json being passed. @JonStirling

Comment: You open the CSV, loop through each line, and append them to the end? I don't see you adding any JSON, only echoing it?

Comment: [json_last_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) might help you debug this.

Comment: I'm kind of running on 4 hours of sleep right now. The json I echoed is sent back to the ajax request for use. I'm trying to use array $data for the csv, not the json

Answer (score 2):

As [the documentation for fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/de/function.fputcsv.php) states: Your second argument has to be an array. In your case $d is a string. What you actually want to do is the following:

```
array_push($data, [date("Y/m/d"), date("h:i:sa"), $email, 'true']);
```

and

```
array_push($data, [date("Y/m/d"), date("h:i:sa"), $email, 'false']);
```